# App says its uninstalled but I can't reinstall it

Tags: amazon-appstore

I downloaded minecraft from the Amazon appstore and installed it to my sd card. My brother removed my sd card, formatted it, and put it back in as a prank. Minecraft said it was still installed, so I uninstalled it. I tried to reinstall it through the Amazon appstore, but the only option was to open the app, which didn't exist. I waited for an update to roll out and clicked the update button. Every time I do this, as soon as i click update the Amazon app crashes. I've checked in the apps section in settings, I've uninstalled and reinstalled Amazon appstore, and I've even tried clearing the data of the app. None of this works.

Answer (score -1):

Try through cmd line

adb install -r yourapp.apk